# jquery-mobile returning blank pages in rails 4 environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile

Some links don't work when I use jquery-mobile with rails and I don't know why. All I get is a blank page. The URL changes, and if I press "refresh" on my browser, the target web page comes up ok. But the web page appears blank when I first click the link.

of the first page:

> ```
> <div data-role="page">
>   <div data-role="ui-content">
>       <a href="/sample_controller/new" data-ajax="false">Click me </a>
>   </div>
> </div>
> ```

of "/sample_controller/new"

> ```
> <div data-role="page">
>    <div data-role="ui-content">
>       Got here
>    </div>
> </div>
> ```

I checked the html headers and the jquery-mobile.js file seems to be loading and it's valid. Same with the stylesheet. No javascript errors come up in my console. Two hints:
1) I checked the DOM in my chrome browser and it says "display: none;" for [data-role=page]. So for some reason jquery-mobile is setting it to be invisible, even though I didn't specify that. 
2) I tried the exact same code with straight HTML (not rails) and the link works fine. So i suspect something in the rails engine is screwing it up.

I tried every avenue including stack overflow. Does anyone know the common reasons why jquery-mobile gives a blank page? Are there any error logs or something in jquery-mobile so I can check to see what's going on?

I am using rails 4.1.7.  and jquery-mobile-rails (loaded in the gemfile) is 3.1.2

Comment: You need to let rails handle navigation not JQM. But I don't know how, because I'm not into rails. Look up JQM and rails navigation.

Comment: No, I added a "<%= link_to "click me", new_sample_path %> and it still exhibited the same behavior. Thank you for trying though.

Comment: Try an anchor link with `data-ajax="false"` or `rel="external"` attribute.

Comment: No, adding rel="external" did not fix it. the "data-ajax='false'' was already there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what went wrong. Omar, in the comments section, was right. I needed to let rails handle navigation not JQM. Apparently, straight "a" links won't work with jquery-mobile within rails, I have to use the "link_to" helper for jquery-mobile to recognize it.

Also, it worked when I installed the jquery_mobile_rails gem directly. before I manually put the jquery_mobile in the assets directory and linked manually. So installing jquery_mobile_rails gem fixed the problem.